# C program from hardware engineer with very little coding background

Tags: c

I am trying to debug this program which I have written, but all I get is the garbage values.

```
/*
 *  Assignment.c
 *
 *  Created on: 18-Aug-2017
 *  Author: sumeetpatil
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char rotateArray(char str[], int degree, int length) {
    char temp[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length + 1; i++) {
        str[i] = str[i] +  &degree;
        str[i] = temp[i];
        //printf ("%c", str[i]);
    }
    return &str;
}

int main() {
    int length;
    int degree;
    char encryptArr[50];

    printf("Enter the value of degree: ", "\n");

    scanf("%d", &degree, "\n");

    printf("Enter the string array you want to encrypt: ", "\n");

    fgets(encryptArr, 100, stdin);

    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &encryptArr);

    length = strlen(encryptArr);

    printf("The character string is: %s\n", encryptArr, "\n");

    printf("The size of character array is %u\n", length);

    rotateArray(encryptArr, degree, length);

    printf("%s\n", rotateArray);
}
```

My output is as follows:

```
Enter the value of degree: 1
Enter the string array you want to encrypt: youmadbro
The character string is: youmadbro
The size of character array is 9
UH��H��@H�a
```

Please let me know what is going wrong in this program.

Comment: Follow compiler warnings! What is the desired output?

Comment: You are assigning your string with value from `temp`, which is undefined.

Comment: Why you're printing the `rotateArray` function name? That's the reason of the gibberish value output.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&degree, "\n");` what exactly are you attempting here?

Comment: for safety, check return values of `scanf`, and use 50 as second argument to `fgets` instead of 100 as there are only 50 char space allocated. other than that and what others have already pointed out, note that `rotateArray` is returning `char **`  which does not match with its return type. Also, note that `scanf("%d",&degree, "\n")` does nto eat the `\n` newline char as you might have intended, instead it is the fgets that reads the null character, which you do not notice as you call  `scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", &encryptArr)` immediately after that.

Comment: You can't learn C by trial and error. You must actually understand what everything you type is doing - there's no guessing. And always make sure your program compiles clean with no warnings. (With the gcc compiler, add flags `-pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra`.)

Comment: How do you develop your code? Do you just edit it in Notepad? Get yourself an IDE, such as Eclipse CDT, NetBeans, MS Visual Studio, etc. Learn how to set breakpoints, step through the code, line by line, examine variables. You will find that a pointer has a NULL value and you are trying to deference it (get the value of what it points to). You have just been taught [how to fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime) :-)

Comment: This is the correct site for code which is not working as it should. Once you have it working, you can get help improving the code at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Your code contains some behaviours that are wrong.

I guess maybe you're coming from another language and attempting to learn C?

Well, let us see what kind of errors in the code that you've made.

---

## 1.

```
char rotateArray(char str[], int degree, int length) {

    char temp[length];
    for(int i=0; i < length +1; i++)
    {
        str[i] = str[i]+ &degree;
        str[i] = temp[i];
        //printf ("%c", str[i]);
        }
    return &str;
}
```

My guess is you're trying to rotate (shift the character) one by one and storing it into the `temp` string array. You don't actually need to store the new rotated value into the a new `temp` because `str` array has already been modified here `str[i] = str[i]+ &degree`. The reason is that in C, an array is passed kind of like reference so you can modify the value and it still gonna 'affects' the `str`'s value outside of it.

So we can remove `temp` array altogether.

```
/* char rotateArray(char str[], int degree, int length) { */
void rotateArray(char str[], int degree, int length) {

    /* char temp[length]; */

    for(int i=0; i < length +1; i++)
    {
        str[i] = str[i]+ degree;
        /* str[i] = temp[i]; */
        //printf ("%c", str[i]);
    }
    /* return &str; */
}
```

---

## 2.

In the main body, almost on every `printf` and `scanf` you've inserted `\n` at the back. I guess again maybe this style of coding was influenced by another programming language? :)

Actually, in C, you don't have to put the `\n` as a new parameter unless you had put specifier at the format string. So you can remove `, "\n"` altogether.

```
/* printf("Enter the value of degree: ", "\n"); */
printf("Enter the value of degree: ");

/* scanf("%d",&degree, "\n"); */
scanf("%d",&degree);

/* printf("Enter the string array you want to encrypt: ", "\n"); */
printf("Enter the string array you want to encrypt: ");

/* printf("The character string is: %s\n", encryptArr, "\n"); */
printf("The character string is: %s\n", encryptArr);
```

`printf` & `scanf` is kinda like a beast to a new C programmer. Please take a look at more resources that discuss those matter.

---

## 3.

Lastly, at the end of your main body,

```
printf("%s\n", rotateArray);
```

This is kinda nonsense because you're trying to print the function name. Well, I guess again maybe you thought that it will print the returned value of the function, right?

Actually, from what I have told you earlier at the top, any string array that passed into the function as a `str` parameter is kinda like a reference, so when you're modifying `str` inside the `rotateArray` body it will 'affect' the value of the main function too.

So instead of that wrong code, you can change it to be like this,

```
/* printf("%s\n", rotateArray); */
printf("%s\n", encryptArr);
```

---

So, the final modified code will be:

```
/*
 *  Assignment.c
 *
 *  Created on: 18-Aug-2017
 *  Author: sumeetpatil
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* char rotateArray(char str[], int degree, int length) { */
void rotateArray(char str[], int degree, int length) {

    /* char temp[length]; */

    for(int i=0; i < length +1; i++)
    {
        str[i] = str[i]+ degree;
        /* str[i] = temp[i]; */
        //printf ("%c", str[i]);
    }
    /* return &str; */
}

int main(){

    int length;
    int degree;
    char encryptArr[50];

    /* printf("Enter the value of degree: ", "\n"); */
    printf("Enter the value of degree: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    /* scanf("%d",&degree, "\n"); */
    scanf("%d",&degree);

    /* printf("Enter the string array you want to encrypt: ", "\n"); */
    printf("Enter the string array you want to encrypt: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    fgets(encryptArr, 100, stdin);

    scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", &encryptArr);

    length = strlen(encryptArr);

    /* printf("The character string is: %s\n", encryptArr, "\n"); */
    printf("The character string is: %s\n", encryptArr);

    printf("The size of character array is %u\n", length);

    rotateArray(encryptArr, degree, length);

    /* printf("%s\n", rotateArray); */
    printf("%s\n", encryptArr);

}
```

---

## Bonus

What're you trying to achieve here is what called as [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).

Your implementation was wrong because it doesn't handle 'alphabet overflow' correctly. What I mean is when your code exceeds `z` it doesn't rotate itself to `a` again. There are many ways to achieve this either by using remainder operator `%` or using `if-else` statement to check either the alphabet has overflowed.

Try to look at the example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher#Example).

Comment: You're missing `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf`s without newlines

Comment: Though OP seems to use a platform where this is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by what is not ok.

```
scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", &encryptArr); //Wrong
scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", &encryptArr[0]); //OK
scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", encryptArr); //OK
```

Now your rotation function.

```
char rotateArray(char str[], int degree, int length) {
    char temp[length]; //Declared on stack, values are not known, UB
    for(int i=0; i < length + 1; i++) { //Why +1? Forces UB in later stage
        str[i] = str[i]+ &degree; //Degree is variable on stack, adding & is just getting address from stack
        str[i] = temp[i]; //Assigning temp value with undefined value
        //printf ("%c", str[i]); //Printing undefined value
        }
    return &str; //You should get at least warning here.
    return str[0]; //Better
}
```

This is now generic. When you will tell us what is desired output according to input, I will be able to tell you more.

```
printf("%s\n", rotateArray);
```

You cannot just print function name as string. This is undefined behavior in C.

Answer (score 0):

The encoding function has problems:

- the loop index should vary from `0` to `len - 1` inclusive, hence the test should be:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { ...
  ```
- shifting the character values by `degree` must be done more carefully, handling lowercase and uppercase characters separately and using a modulo computation for a circular permutation.
- to use the value of `degree`, you do not need the `&` addressof operator.
- the string is modified in place, you do not need a temporary array.

Here is a corrected version:

```
char *rotateArray(char *str, int degree, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = str[i];
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            str[i] = 'a' + (c - 'a' + degree) % 26;
        } else
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
            str[i] = 'A' + (c - 'A' + degree) % 26;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

The `main()` function has problems too:

- `fgets()` and `scanf()` are 2 different ways to read the string, just use one.
- The second argument to `fgets(encryptArr, 100, stdin);` should be `50` or `sizeof(encryptArr)` to tell `fgets()` the size of the destination array and prevent buffer overflow.
- You pass extra `"\n"` arguments to `scanf()` and `printf()` that are ignored. Enable compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra`) and study the messages.
- function `rotateArray()` modifies `encryptArr` in place, you should pass `encryptArr` to `printf()` instead of the function name.

Here is a corrected version:

```
int main(void) {
    int length;
    int degree;
    char encryptArr[50];

    printf("Enter the value of degree: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &degree) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("Enter the string array you want to encrypt: ");
    if (!fgets(encryptArr, sizeof(encryptArr), stdin))
        return 1;

    length = strlen(encryptArr);
    printf("The character string is: %s\n", encryptArr);
    printf("The length of character string is %d\n", length);

    rotateArray(encryptArr, degree, length);
    printf("%s\n", encryptArr);

    return 0;
}
```

Finally, you include `<stdio.h>` twice. While it does not cause a problem, you should only include header files once and only those needed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: @SumeetPatil: did this answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
char *rotateArray(char *str, int degree, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = str[i];
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            str[i] = 'a' + (c - 'a' + degree) % 26;
        } else
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
            str[i] = 'A' + (c - 'A' + degree) % 26;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```